# Get program icons

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm making a explorer like app to browse files stored on my computer. My app will be in "Icon" view. The question is: How to display the icon of an exe file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. The easiest is probably to add a reference to `System.Drawing` and take advantage of the `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon` method:

```cs
public static ImageSource GetIcon(string fileName)
{
    Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fileName);
    return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                icon.Handle, 
                new Int32Rect(icon.Width, icon.Height),
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}
```

Another option, if you don't want to use `System.Drawing`, is to obtain the icon from the `SHGetFileInfo` API. It's more difficult, but also much more flexible; for instance you can get the icon of a file that doesn't exist, based on the extension (of course for an executable it's not very useful, since it would return the default icon for executable files).

```cs
public static ImageSource GetIcon(string path, bool smallIcon, bool isDirectory)
{
    // SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES takes the file name and attributes into account if it doesn't exist
    uint flags = SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES;
    if (smallIcon)
        flags |= SHGFI_SMALLICON;

    uint attributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;
    if (isDirectory)
        attributes |= FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY;

    SHFILEINFO shfi;
    if (0 != SHGetFileInfo(
                path,
                attributes,
                out shfi,
                (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SHFILEINFO)),
                flags))
    {
        return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                    shfi.hIcon, 
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
    return null;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct SHFILEINFO
{
    public IntPtr hIcon;
    public int iIcon;
    public uint dwAttributes;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string szDisplayName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
    public string szTypeName;
}

    [DllImport("shell32")]
    private static extern int SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint dwFileAttributes, out SHFILEINFO psfi, uint cbFileInfo, uint flags);

private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY = 0x00000001;
private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN = 0x00000002;
private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM = 0x00000004;
private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0x00000010;
private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE = 0x00000020;
private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE = 0x00000040;
private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 0x00000080;
private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY = 0x00000100;
private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE = 0x00000200;
private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT = 0x00000400;
private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED = 0x00000800;
private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE = 0x00001000;
private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED = 0x00002000;
private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED = 0x00004000;
private const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL = 0x00010000;

private const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x000000100;     // get icon
private const uint SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME = 0x000000200;     // get display name
private const uint SHGFI_TYPENAME = 0x000000400;     // get type name
private const uint SHGFI_ATTRIBUTES = 0x000000800;     // get attributes
private const uint SHGFI_ICONLOCATION = 0x000001000;     // get icon location
private const uint SHGFI_EXETYPE = 0x000002000;     // return exe type
private const uint SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX = 0x000004000;     // get system icon index
private const uint SHGFI_LINKOVERLAY = 0x000008000;     // put a link overlay on icon
private const uint SHGFI_SELECTED = 0x000010000;     // show icon in selected state
private const uint SHGFI_ATTR_SPECIFIED = 0x000020000;     // get only specified attributes
private const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x000000000;     // get large icon
private const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x000000001;     // get small icon
private const uint SHGFI_OPENICON = 0x000000002;     // get open icon
private const uint SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE = 0x000000004;     // get shell size icon
private const uint SHGFI_PIDL = 0x000000008;     // pszPath is a pidl
private const uint SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES = 0x000000010;     // use passed dwFileAttribute
```

Another advantage of this approach is that it can also get the icon for a directory (see last edit in the code), which isn't possible with `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon`

Comment: Which feature? Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon? It's not part of WPF itself, but it's in the .NET Framework. System.Drawing is just a wrapper for GDI

Comment: I can't import System.Drawing Namespace in WPF, how do I get the Icon class?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you need to *add a reference* to the `System.Drawing` assembly (you also need to import the namespace of course)