# How do I extract Icons embedded into a .exe using WPF?

Tags: wpf, icons, exe

Given a folder full of .exe files, I need to build a toolbar that displays each .exe file's embedded icon. I've seen solutions using WinForms ( [Get program icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008600/get-program-icons) ) , but how can I do this using WPF?

Also, due to the nature of the task, it needs to be done dynamically using C#, not with Xaml.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in that post is about WPF. It returns an ImageSource. WPF's Image class handles that just fine using the Source property.

```
someImage.Source = GetIcon(somePath); // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008600/get-program-icons
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I knew how to add a reference, and didn't understand why it didn't recognize the System.Drawing namespace. I was introduced to this a couple days ago. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Right click on the 'References' item in the solution explorer and select "Add Reference". Locate "System.Drawing.dll" inside the dialog presented to you and double click it. Finally click OK.